# R extract info from pairs plot click

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I would like to be able to get info on a scatterplot matrix (using pairs or something similar) when a user clicks on a section of the matrix.  All I simply need is to determine which x and y variables intersect where the user click so I can load up another page that has just a single plot with those 2 same variables.

Comment: It's easier to help if you provide some sort of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that could be used to test possible solutions.

Comment: I don't know if `plotly` for R will do everything that you want, but you may want to look at the [plotly](https://plot.ly/r/) website.